# Yii2 controller render() function only render the layouts/main?

Tags: php, yii2

In my SiteController under namespace repo/controllers call

```
return $this->render('index');
```

it only render the /views/layouts/main.php but I need to render the /views/site/index.php alone with the layouts files.

If I change into

```
return $this->renderPartial('index');
```

it renders the /views/site/index.php without problem. So what's the problem with the render() function??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, make sure you didn't missed `<?= $content ?>` at your layouts/main.php. That should render your content

Comment: oh, I trace into the basecontroller then find the $content ,,,But i forgot to add it into the main.php.

Comment: and if I forgot <?php $this->beginPage() ?> what will happen?

Comment: It just trigger event EVENT_BEGIN_PAGE. You can see examples of Yii2 events [here](http://developer.uz/blog/event-for-behavior-in-yii2/) .

Comment: Also you can check other methods of View class [here] (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#creating-layouts) . There are some methods to mark starting of content, html body, etc.